# css position, border radius, overflow not respected in webkit - other solutions?

Tags: webkit, position, overflow, css

So I have a fake little iOS 5 style switch I built using the technique where you use a smaller div as a viewport and a larger div as the content visible through that viewport.  It totally failed in webkit because with a position besides static set on any child element it does not respect the border radius when calculating the overflow as being hidden.

[Original effort on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B3yV4/1/)

[Solution on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pfp3K/1/)

Really, I'm wondering 3 things:

1. Why hasn't webkit confirmed this as a bug yet?  (https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72619)
2. Are there any other workarounds for this bug that people know of - specifically for the viewport technique I described?
3. More of a sidenote, really.  Does the viewport technique have an actual formal name that I should be calling it?

Comment: I'm not sure about 1, but it sure is a bug. The CSS spec is explicit that border-radius changes the padding edge, which is the point for overflow clipping. The only other technique I can think of is to add a child element that uses a part-transparent image to act as a crude clipping mask - so the switch 'holder' is actually the child. Not a nice solution, though.

Comment: I copied and pasted the code for testing and I ran it on localhost with Google Chrome. I can't figure out why it runs correctly except for the circle between warm and cold being positioned at the beginning of the warm div.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure I really understand how you did it. It seemed quite striahgtforward to me:

http://jsfiddle.net/5qs26/